# A fatal error is detected by the JRE with CPLEX LazyCallBack

Tags: java, cplex

I have a problem while running a branch-and-cut for the Inventory Routing Problem with cplex's LazyCallback.

```
public class lazyConstraintCallback extends IloCplex.LazyConstraintCallback {

private IloCplex cplex;
private IloNumVar[][][][] x;
private IloNumVar[][][] y;
private int nbLocations;
private int horizon;
private int nbVehicles;
private double[][] graph;
private boolean subtour;

public lazyConstraintCallback (IloCplex cplex, IloNumVar[][][][] x, IloNumVar[][][] y, int nbLocations, int horizon, int nbVehicles, double[][] graph, boolean subtour) {
    this.cplex=cplex;
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.nbLocations=nbLocations;
    this.horizon=horizon;
    this.nbVehicles=nbVehicles;
    this.graph=graph;
    this.subtour=subtour;
}

protected void main() throws IloException {
    this.graph= new double[this.nbLocations][this.nbLocations];
    for(int t=0;t<this.horizon;t++) {
        for(int k=0;k<this.nbVehicles;k++) {
            double tourlength=1;
            for(int i=1;i<this.nbLocations;i++) {
                if(getValue(y[i][t][k])>0.1) {
                    tourlength++;
                }
            }
            int[] subtour = null;
            if(tourlength>5) {
                for(int i=0;i<this.nbLocations;i++) {
                    for(int j=i+1;j<this.nbLocations;j++) {
                        graph[i][j]=getValue(x[i][j][t][k]);
                    }
                }
                subtour=this.getSubtours(graph, tourlength);
                if(this.subtour) {
                    IloLinearNumExpr expr = this.cplex.linearNumExpr();
                    for (int i=0;i<subtour.length; i++) {
                        for (int j=i+1;j<subtour.length;j++) {
                            if (subtour[i] < subtour[j]) {
                                expr.addTerm(1, this.x[subtour[i]][subtour[j]][t][k]);
                            } else {
                                expr.addTerm(1, this.x[subtour[j]][subtour[i]][t][k]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    IloRange SEC = this.cplex.le(expr, subtour.length-1);
                    this.cplex.addLazyConstraint(SEC);
                    System.out.println(SEC);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the problem occurs when the SEC cut is added. However, it doesn't seem that there is any problem with the cut as you can see in the following:

```
IloRange  : -infinity <= (1.0*x_{2,5}^{1,2} + 1.0*x_{2,6}^{1,2} + 1.0*x_{5,6}^{1,2}) <= 2.0
```

I would appreciate the help if someone has an idea.

This is the error message:

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000012cc5020b, pid=7202, tid=10499

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (10.0.1+10) (build 10.0.1+10)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (10.0.1+10, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, bsd-amd64)
 Problematic frame:
 C  [libcplex1271remotejni.jnilib+0x73920b]  _72f67b7f5c69d5c29f1bcb05ad4e6d45+0x1b

No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

An error report file with more information is saved as:
 /Users/faycal/Desktop/AcademicWork/info/workspace/IRP/hs_err_pid7202.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
this.cplex.addLazyConstraint(SEC);
```

What you are doing here is adding a lazy constraints to the the models **static** lazy constraint table. As this is part of the model, it is not allowed to modify this during optimization. In order to add a lazy constraint from a callback, use the callback's `add()` method:

```
add(SEC);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This fixed the problem. However, i would like to ask what's the use of the addLazyConstraint() method in this case?

Comment: There are two options to add lazy constraints: 1. You can add all the lazy constraints *before* you start the optimization vial `solve()`. This is done using `addLazyConstraints()` and is useful if the lazy constraints are easy to enumerate and their number is relatively small. 2. You can dynamically separate lazy constraints with a callback (like you did). This is useful in case there are a lot of lazy constraints (in particular if there is an exponential number of them).